# How to use Auth in MongoDB after adding a root user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, remote-access, remote-server

I need to connect to to my MongoDB remotely. So I've commented out the line `bind_ip` in the `mongod.conf` and set there also `auth=true`. Now I was able to connect remotely.

Then I typed following on the machine running mongodb:

1. `use admin`
2. `db.addUser("myadmin", "mypw")`

Was created successfully but now when I try to connect remotely or even on the local machine and I try to execute anything it sais: `not authorized on admin to execute command`

Even that I try to connect like this: `mongo -u myadmin -p mypw` (locally)

I get following error:

`MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
2015-04-08T15:25:53.425+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1260
exception: login failed`

Maybe because he tries to connect to the `test` db? How can I specify which db. Remotely it doesn't work with `mongo --host myurl -u myadmin-p mypw`
with following error:

`2015-04-08T14:31:00.373+0200 E QUERY    Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }
    at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1236:32)
    at (auth):6:8
    at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1236
exception: login failed`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try to use `--authenticationDatabase` while connecting to mongo shell, like in the following:

```
mongo -u myadmin -p mypw --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: No problem - got the same problem few weeks ago and it took me some time to figure out what I was doing wrong :)